# Non-polynomial solutions for a functional inequality

Tags: functions, inequality, functional-inequalities

Let $c>0$ be a constant real number.

**(a)** Is there any non-polynomial real function $f$ satisfying the inequality
$$
-\frac{1}{c}x^2+\frac{1}{c}yx<f(y)-f(x)<\frac{1}{c}y^2-\frac{1}{c}xy\; ; \;\;\; x< y ?
$$

If yes, are there **infinitely many** such functions?

(Note that the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{2c}t^2$ is a solution, but it is a polynomial)

**(b)** Does exist another polynomial solution (except that $f(t)=\frac{1}{2c}t^2$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to $x < \frac{c(f(y)-f(x))}{y - x}$ < y (factor $y-x$ out on the outsides and divide by it) so in particular the limits as $y$ tends to $x$ from above and as x tends to y from below give differentiability and $f'(x) = \frac{x}{c}$ at every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So your solution plus an arbitrary constant is the only kind of solution.

Comment: Good, the first inequality is $x < \frac{c(f(y)-f(x))}{y - x}< y$.

Comment: True, thanks, I fixed it.